# Magento 2.3.7-p2 issue with PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution

Tags: magento, paypal

I'm new to Magento community. I'm facing an issue with PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution. Please help me to solve this issue.

First I tested Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution with sandbox credentials, it worked without any issue. Then I changed the sandbox credentials to live credentials. After that whenever I'm trying to checkout using PayPal, instead of asking for card details, it is redirecting me to a PayPal error page(screenshot attached).

I contacted PayPal with the error, as per them, Magento is not sharing data with PayPal, that's why it is throwing error.

I'm not sure what to do now. I need some assistance. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: This is an issue for PayPal or Magento's support, but likely PayPal's to begin with. Begin by confirming that your live PayPal account is enabled for hosted sole solution and that the credentials and configuration in Magento is correct.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I verified my business by submitting all the required documents. Is there anything else that I need to do? Or how I can check whether my account has the provision for hosted solution?

Comment: That's a question for PayPal